timezone.today() - timezone.today() creates different results between windows and linux
Basically the title.
My tests were failing on the linux machine, but locally in windows they were successful. I created a minimal (not) working example:
On windows:
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.today() - datetime.today()
datetime.timedelta(0)
>>> (datetime.today() - datetime.today()).days
0

On linux (and wsl2):
In[6]: from datetime import datetime
In[7]: datetime.today() - datetime.today()
Out[7]: datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=86399, microseconds=999986)
In[21]: (datetime.today() - datetime.today()).days
Out[21]: -1

I would expect that this would produce the same results, but the results differs by one day.
Is there any documentation on that?

You're calling datetime.today() twice so you should probably expect some amount of time to pass between the 2 calls. That said it would depend on the resolution of the clock being polled and perhaps the performance of the 2 computers being compared to tell whether that difference is very close to zero or basically zero. I wouldn't consider any difference to be a Python issue.

The difference is just negative 14 µs. Please read the note "normalization of negative values may be surprising at first" at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta
